# What does the current literature say on the relationship of psychedelic drugs and neuroplasticity?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, neurophysiology, psychedelics

The majority of my understanding of the current literature comes from [this](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41386-022-01389-z) paper found in Nature.

The purpose of the paper is to examine "specific questions about the effects of psychedelics on neuroplasticity."

As a complete outsider, I am unable to differentiate the woowoo papers from the serious, generally accepted science. I've read through the paper and it answered most of the questions I have here, but asking in this forum seems more likely to yield accurate answers.

These are not separate questions, but more qualifications of what it means to answer "current literature" on a subject.

1. What is the proposed mechanism of action for increasing neuroplasticity via the use of psychadelic drugs? Is this mechanism of action reasonable?
2. How long do these neuroplastic effects last?
3. What are the outcomes and consequences of this potential relationship (if we assume that there is one).

Again, note that these questions are answered in the specific study mentioned, but I'm asking about the overall body of literature rather than a single analysis.

Comment: I work in a lab that does some work in psychedelics...none of the three questions you ask have known answers. I think the review you refer to is a good starting place. One thing to be wary about is that most of the work done in humans is in very small samples, not pre-registered, and hasn't necessarily been replicated by others (including some seemingly opposite effects). There is also quite a cultural divergence in the field between those interested in psychedelics as therapy and those interested in psychedelics as psychotomimetic (e.g., as a model system for understanding schizophrenia).

Comment: @BryanKrause Thanks for responding. I figured that research would be lacking. Would you have any other recommendations for serious studies on neuroplasticity and pharmaceuticals? Not necessarily just psychedelics.

Comment: Neuroplasticity is an absolutely massive field, ranging from really well-done cellular physiology to scammy brain games sold to elderly folks with a promise to boost their cognition. If you're brand new to the field, I'd start by learning about studies of "long term potentiation" in brain slice preparations.